# Dataloader throwing error TypeError: new(): data must be a sequence (got map)

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to implement bidirectional LSTM on time series data. The main file calls the dataloader to load the data for the model.

Main.py

```
import copy
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR

import numpy as np

import time
import utils
import models
from models import rits_i
from models import brits_i
from models import rits
from models import brits

import argparse
import data_loader
import pandas as pd
import ujson as json

from sklearn import metrics

from ipdb import set_trace

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--epochs', type = int, default = 1000)
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type = int, default = 32)
parser.add_argument('--model', type = str)
args = parser.parse_args()

def train(model):
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-3)

    data_iter = data_loader.get_loader(batch_size = args.batch_size)

    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        model.train()

        run_loss = 0.0

        for idx, data in enumerate(data_iter):
            data = utils.to_var(data)
            ret = model.run_on_batch(data, optimizer)

            run_loss += ret['loss'].data[0]

            print('\r Progress epoch {}, {:.2f}%, average loss {}'.format(epoch, (idx + 1) * 100.0 / len(data_iter), run_loss / (idx + 1.0)),)

        if epoch % 1 == 0:
            evaluate(model, data_iter)

def evaluate(model, val_iter):
    model.eval()

    labels = []
    preds = []

    evals = []
    imputations = []

    for idx, data in enumerate(val_iter):
        data = utils.to_var(data)
        ret = model.run_on_batch(data, None)

        pred = ret['predictions'].data.cpu().numpy()
        label = ret['labels'].data.cpu().numpy()
        is_train = ret['is_train'].data.cpu().numpy()

        eval_masks = ret['eval_masks'].data.cpu().numpy()
        eval_ = ret['evals'].data.cpu().numpy()
        imputation = ret['imputations'].data.cpu().numpy()

        evals += eval_[np.where(eval_masks == 1)].tolist()
        imputations += imputation[np.where(eval_masks == 1)].tolist()

        # collect test label & prediction
        pred = pred[np.where(is_train == 0)]
        label = label[np.where(is_train == 0)]

        labels += label.tolist()
        preds += pred.tolist()

    labels = np.asarray(labels).astype('int32')
    preds = np.asarray(preds)

    print('AUC {}'.format(metrics.roc_auc_score(labels, preds)))

    evals = np.asarray(evals)
    imputations = np.asarray(imputations)

    print('MAE', np.abs(evals - imputations).mean())
    print('MRE', np.abs(evals - imputations).sum() / np.abs(evals).sum())

def run():
    model = getattr(models, args.model).Model()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model = model.cuda()

    train(model)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

data_loader.py

```
import os
import time

import ujson as json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class MySet(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySet, self).__init__()
        self.content = open('./json/json').readlines()

        indices = np.arange(len(self.content))
        val_indices = np.random.choice(indices, len(self.content) // 5)

        self.val_indices = set(val_indices.tolist())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.content)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        rec = json.loads(self.content[idx])
        if idx in self.val_indices:
            rec['is_train'] = 0
        else:
            rec['is_train'] = 1
        return rec

def collate_fn(recs):
    forward = map(lambda x: x['forward'], recs)
    backward = map(lambda x: x['backward'], recs)

    def to_tensor_dict(recs):
        values = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['values'], r), recs))
        masks = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['masks'], r), recs))
        deltas = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['deltas'], r), recs))
        forwards = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['forwards'], r), recs))

        evals = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['evals'], r), recs))
        eval_masks = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['eval_masks'], r), recs))

        return {'values': values, 'forwards': forwards, 'masks': masks, 'deltas': deltas, 'evals': evals, 'eval_masks': eval_masks}

    ret_dict = {'forward': to_tensor_dict(forward), 'backward': to_tensor_dict(backward)}

    ret_dict['labels'] = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda x: x['label'], recs))
    ret_dict['is_train'] = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda x: x['is_train'], recs))

    return ret_dict

def get_loader(batch_size = 64, shuffle = True):
    data_set = MySet()
    data_iter = DataLoader(dataset = data_set, \
                              batch_size = batch_size, \
                              num_workers = 4, \
                              shuffle = shuffle, \
                              pin_memory = True, \
                              collate_fn = collate_fn
    )

    return data_iter
```

but I am unable to resolve the error TypeError: new(): data must be a sequence (got map)

Following message is being received in the terminal:

```
C:\Users\ankit\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 61292 --file C:/Users/ankit/PycharmProjects/BRITS/main.py --epochs 1000 --batch_size 32 --model brits
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.4746.96)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1203, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1229, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\_utils.py", line 425, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\BRITS\data_loader.py", line 48, in collate_fn
    ret_dict = {'forward': to_tensor_dict(forward), 'backward': to_tensor_dict(backward)}
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\BRITS\data_loader.py", line 38, in to_tensor_dict
    values = torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['values'], r), recs))
TypeError: new(): data must be a sequence (got map)
```

The input data is in the jason format (below is the partial data):

```
{"forward":[{"evals":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.9056552797,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.6644796629,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2233221525,0.9872348884,1.5032897407,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.1197213235,0.0,0.0,-1.2017103673,0.0,0.0,2.16039189,0.0],"deltas":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"forwards":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.9056552797,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.6644796629,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2233221525,0.9872348884,1.5032897407,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.1197213235,0.0,0.0,-1.2017103673,0.0,0.0,2.16039189,0.0],"masks":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],"values":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.9056552797,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.6644796629,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2233221525,0.9872348884,1.5032897407,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.1197213235,0.0,0.0,-1.2017103673,0.0,0.0,2.16039189,0.0],"eval_masks":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"evals":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.5117099666,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2569139277,0.6703649195,0.8156657086,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.3034796866,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.5174302535,0.0],"deltas":[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0],"forwards":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.9056552797,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.5117099666,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2569139277,0.6703649195,0.8156657086,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.3034796866,0.0,0.0,-1.2017103673,0.0,0.0,-0.5174302535,0.0],"masks":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],"values":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.5117099666,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2569139277,0.6703649195,0.8156657086,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.3034796866,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.5174302535,0.0],"eval_masks":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"evals":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.3987459261,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.4149215779,-0.0992249514,0.1738832786,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.1197213235,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.3156699689,0.0],"deltas":[2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0]
```

I researched and got that it might be issue with python 3 but I ran on python 2 but still facing the same issue. Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked or tried running all of your code, but at a glance, this line is clearly wrong

```
torch.FloatTensor(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['values'], r), recs))
```

In python3, `map()` returns a `map` object, not a list. `FloatTensor(..)` expects the later, i.e. a list. Just cast all your map objects with `list()`

```
torch.FloatTensor(list(map(lambda r: map(lambda x: x['values'], r), recs)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a map to `torch.*Tensor` won't work, you have to first convert it to a *list*. The issue is your map itself contains *map* objects. An alternative solution is to use a single list comprehension, which is straightforward:

```
>>> torch.FloatTensor([recs for recs in x['values']])
```